# Is Passport enough as proof of citizenship when applying for I-130?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I am a naturalized American citizen and I am filing for my parent's I-130. Now, on the USCIS website, in `proof of citizenship` section it says:

Upload documents that show that you are a U.S. citizen. Examples of these documents include:

```
A copy of your birth certificate, issued by a civil registrar, vital statistics office, or other civil authority showing that you were born in the United States
A copy of your naturalization certificate or certificate of citizenship issued by USCIS or the former Immigration and Naturalization Service (INS)
A copy of Form FS-240, Consular Report of Birth Abroad (CRBA), issued by a U.S. Embassy or U.S. Consulate
A copy of your unexpired U.S. passport
An original statement from a U.S. consular officer verifying that you are a U.S. citizen with a valid passport
```

What I am failing to understand in these instructions is that IF these documents are all required or one of them is sufficed?

I do have a US Passport. I also do have a naturalization certificate but it's a little torn so I prefer that if my passport is enough then I would like to submit only the passport. However, in these instructions, it is not very clear that which or all of these docs are required?

Comment: It cannot be "all" because, for example, a person was either born in the US or abroad, not both. They were either a citizen from birth, or naturalized.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that they can’t require all the documents, as (virtually? There may be a counter example) no one will possess the all of the first three on the list.

Comment: @rhialto I can't think of any circumstances in which someone could have both a US birth certificate and a consular report of birth abroad.  Maybe someone born in a foreign territory that later became a US state, but I don't think that's happened since the US began issuing consular reports of birth abroad.

Comment: My question was more around requiring both naturalization very and US passport. Sorry if I want very clear on my question.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the child of a diplomat can be both born in the US and naturalized.  However, such a person is not a citizen from birth, so the second sentence is true for the child of a diplomat.  My father, however, is both naturalized and a citizen from birth: he was naturalized in the 1950s and then in 1994 a law was passed making him (along with others in his situation), retroactively, a citizen from birth.  But he doesn't have a CRBA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a valid US passport is enough. Any one of the items is enough. See the [I-130 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-130instr.pdf), General Requirements #3 (page 6):

> 3. What documents do you need to show that you are a U.S. citizen?
>
> A. A copy of your birth certificate, issued by a civil registrar,
>   vital statistics office, or other civil authority showing that you
>   were born in the United States;
>
> B. A copy of your naturalization certificate or certificate of
>   citizenship issued by USCIS or the former Immigration and
>   Naturalization Service (INS);
>
> C. A copy of Form FS-240, Consular Report of Birth Abroad (CRBA),
>   issued by a U.S. Embassy or U.S. Consulate;
>
> D. A copy of your unexpired U.S. passport; or
>
> E. An original statement from a U.S. consular officer verifying that
>   you are a U.S. citizen with a valid passport.
>
> If you do not have any of the above documents and you were born in the
>   United States, see the What if an official document is not available
>   section of these Instructions.

The "or" indicates that any one of the items is sufficient.